# Off-the-chain rules vs. on-chain-rules when designing a DAO

Tags: contract-development, contract-design, dao

Imagine such DAO, where there are two actors:

- `Business`
- `Partners`

What a `business` can do are:

- Issue a `certificate` to `partners`, which uses certain off-the-chian logic to evaluate the traits of the `partners`,
- Advertise to all `partners` a `JobPost` available from the `business`, the `JobPost` may need 1 or many `partners` to fill in.

To fill a `JobPost`:

- Either a `parter` can apply for it bidding with a competitive rate,
- Or the `busienss` can offer/hunt for `partner actively.

Once the `JobPost` is filled, a `WorkContract` is signed where certain amount of token is locked and can be released to the `partners` when either triggered by `business` or timeout (in block time)

The philosophical question is, should the decision of filling the `JobPost` made off-the-chain by the entity represents (holding the private key) the `business`, or the filling rules itself should be part of the original `JobPost` itself.

Technically we can do both. But if we use blockchain, to what extent we want to use the blockchain, is another way to generalize the question.

Hope it is a understandable question!

Answer (score 2):

I think you carefully the business rules you want to enforce. The certificates is basically about an onboarding process with some external oversight.

You can make it so partners are obligated to accept bids along the lines of an order book for normalized commodities, or you can make it so partners choose who they want to hire. You may even want to support both options with some sort of order type.

Unless the hiring decision is involved in a subsequent step with on-chain logic (such as delivery and payment settlement) it's not clear the hiring decision needs to be recorded on the chain at all. You may find that most of it can be handled off-chain, and the smart contract provides an assurance of that certificate (on-boarding). https://medium.com/solidified/the-joy-of-minimalism-in-smart-contract-design-b67fb4073422

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply! I added an edit that emphasizes that it does involve singing a work contract which involves token transfering.

Comment: I think you'll do okay if you think along the lines of the proposed business arrangement. It's basically about whether automatic order-matching or voluntary association is more appropriate for your case. You might find the blockchain is best used to establish trust and remove uncertainty but not necessarily to force people into an association.